# IONIC 3 "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0"

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage

I get this error: **Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.** in my database provider ... i'm trying to make a localstorage.

database.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable()
export class DatabaseProvider {


  local : any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello DatabaseProvider Provider');

    this.local = new Storage();
  }

}
```

my error is the line when a created a new storage "this.local = new Storage();" ... so, the Storage() it seems to wait for an argument ... what argument? i've tried with "localstorage" but it still no working

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with SQLite

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';


@Injectable()
export class DatabaseProvider {


  local : any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello DatabaseProvider Provider');

    this.local = new SQLite();
  }

}
```

Or (but I believe SqlStorage is deprecated)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Storage, SqlStorage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable()
export class DatabaseProvider {


  local : any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello DatabaseProvider Provider');

    this.local = new Storage(SqlStorage);
  }

}
```